# Accessing Cocoa from Ruby with FFI?

Tags: ruby, cocoa, ffi

Is it possible to use the Cocoa API from Ruby loading the libraries with FFI? I know that you can access those libraries with RubyCocoa or MacRuby, but I would rather stick to "normal" ruby if possible. I have read that RubyCocoa uses libffi (on which if I'm not mistaken FFI relies) to tap into the libraries, so maybe it is possible to do the same with FFI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, but not in a very useful fashion.

Here is a fully functional example:

```
require 'ffi'

module ObjC
  extend FFI::Library

  ffi_lib 'objc'

  attach_function :sel_registerName, [:string], :pointer
  attach_function :objc_msgSend, [:pointer, :pointer, :varargs], :pointer
  def self.msgSend( id, selector, *args )
    selector = sel_registerName(selector) if selector.is_a? String
    return objc_msgSend( id, selector, *args )
  end
  attach_function :objc_getClass, [:string], :pointer
end

module Cocoa
  extend FFI::Library

  ffi_lib '/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Cocoa'

  attach_function :NSApplicationLoad, [], :bool
  NSApplicationLoad()
 end

pool = ObjC.msgSend(ObjC.msgSend(ObjC.objc_getClass("NSAutoreleasePool"),"alloc"),"init")
application = ObjC.msgSend(ObjC.objc_getClass("NSApplication"),"sharedApplication")
ObjC.msgSend(application,"run")
```